# Jsoup in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsoup

I have used Jsoup Library to extract html from different sites.
Jsoup Post to be Precised.
When i use it locally ie in  java dynamic web application it runs perfectly fine.
But when i try to run on google app engine , it doesnot give required and expected data that i get when i run the program locally.

I use the below code to get the PNR status of the train. It works fine locally. In google app engine it doesnot return the required data

```
doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnrstat_cgi.cgi").timeout(300000)
                    .data("lccp_pnrno1",fullpnr).post();
```

Comment: As phrased, this is nearly unanswerable. What data do you expect? What's being returned? Do your logs indicate any sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ah , still i was not able to figure it out , but i am getting the result when the application is deployed and is up and running.

I am not getting the result when i run the code locally as a google app engine web application .I used GAE plugin for eclipse. Dont know what the issue is.But it runs when it is deployed so it does solve my problem in a way. :)

Thanks

here is the link to test :  http://train-inquiry.appspot.com/